# How to pass groovy variable to shell script in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In the Jenkinsfile under script section, I am using the following code to return output something like the following.

```
deleting 1
deleting 2
deleting 3
```

I have tried the following script but it seems to be not working.

```
script {
       prdirectory_lists = ['1','2','3']
       def size3 = prdirectory_lists.size()

        for(k=0;k<size3;k++){
        sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'ssh user1@192.168.1.12 echo deleting prdirectory_lists[k] ')
        //sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'ssh user1@192.168.1.12 echo deleting ${prdirectory_lists[k]} ')
        //sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'ssh user1@192.168.1.12 echo "deleting ${prdirectory_lists[k]}" ')
         }
}
```

Comment: I have found the solution.

Comment: Used the following code.
sh(script:"user1@192.168.1.12 echo ${prdirectory_lists[k]}", returnStatus:true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the correct String Interpolation which is `"${variable}"` to access the value of a variable.

```
sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'ssh user1@192.168.1.12 echo deleting "${prdirectory_lists[k]}" ')
```

The official Jenkins documentation has some good examples for this: [String interpolation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        sh returnStdout: true, 
           script: """ssh user1@192.168.1.12 echo "deleting ${prdirectory_lists[k]}" """
```

Answer (score 0):

You always use single quoted strings that do not have a string interpolation facility

The following should work:

```
def list = ['1','2','3']

list.each {item ->
   sh(returnStdout: true, script: "ssh user1@192.168.1.12 echo deleting $item")
}
```

All in all there are three types of strings in Groovy:

1. Single Quoted - like usual java strings without string interpolation
2. Double Quoted - Single line strings with an interpolation facility
3. Triple Quoted - Multi line string with an interpolation facility

I believe Doble Quoted strings will suit you best in this case